# Cmake qt project link error( undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) )

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, cmake

This is the file structure of the program.
It simply creates a window.

```
    test
    │  CMakeLists.txt
    │  main.cpp
    │  mainwindow.cpp
    |  mainwindow.h
    |  mainwindow.ui
```

cmakelists.txt

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
    project(test)
    set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "G:/qt/5.12.10/mingw73_64")#my qt path
    set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
    
    
    if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.7.0")
        set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
    endif()
    find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
    
    add_executable(main main.cpp mainwindow.cpp mainwindow.h mainwindow.ui)
    
    target_link_libraries(main Qt5::Widgets)
```

part of error message:

```
[ 20%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target main
[ 20%] Built target main_autogen
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target main
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/mainwindow.cpp.obj
[ 60%] Linking CXX executable main.exe
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) public: static struct QMetaObject const QMainWindow::staticMetaObject
>>> referenced by CMakeFiles/main.dir/main_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj:(void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for `public: static struct QMetaObject const MainWindow::staticMetaObject''(void))

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __cdecl QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void) const
>>> referenced by F:\test\part1\ui\debug\main_autogen\EWIEGA46WW\moc_mainwindow.cpp:77
>>>               CMakeFiles/main.dir/main_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj:(public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl MainWindow::metaObject(void) const)

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void * __cdecl QMainWindow::qt_metacast(char const *)
>>> referenced by F:\test\part1\ui\debug\main_autogen\EWIEGA46WW\moc_mainwindow.cpp:85
>>>               CMakeFiles/main.dir/main_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj:(public: virtual void * __cdecl MainWindow::qt_metacast(char const *))
```

This seems to be a link error, but I have linked QT's Library in cmakelists.How can I solve it?

#### EDIT 1

I change my compiler to gcc and link successfully( It seems something wrong with my clang).
Now I move the folder to another cmake project and make it a subdirectory of the program. The file structure like following:

```
project
|       external/
|       include/
|       src/
|       test/
|       ui/(*The folder above)
|       CMakeLists.txt
```

root CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)
project(test)
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "G:/qt/5.12.10/mingw73_64")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
link_directories(
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external
)
include_directories(
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(ui)
enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(test)
```

I use `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"` to build cmake. After `make`,The same error occurred:

```
[ 71%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/test_goodsrecord.dir/test_goodsrecord.cpp.obj
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) public: static struct QMetaObject const QMainWindow::staticMetaObject
>>> referenced by CMakeFiles/main.dir/main_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj:(void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for `public: static struct QMetaObject const MainWindow::staticMetaObject''(void))

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __cdecl QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void) const
>>> referenced by F:\test\part1\build\ui\main_autogen\EWIEGA46WW\moc_mainwindow.cpp:77
>>>               CMakeFiles/main.dir/main_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj:(public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl MainWindow::metaObject(void) const)
```

#### EDIT 2

##### my environment

###### gcc

gcc installed in MinGW installer
Thread model: posix
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

###### clang

Use LLVM WIN64 installer to install.
clang version 12.0.0
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin

###### cmake

cmake version 3.20.0

Comment: Can you be more specific about your environment and add this information to the question? MinGW compiler version, whether you use CLion, mingw64 or MSYS/MSYS2 ...?

Comment: @vre  ok. I have added these information.

Comment: You're messing up with Q_DECL_EXPORT/Q_DECL_IMPORT in your mainwindow.h so the linker thinks the MainWindow class is imported but it's not. Remove those macros.

Comment: @chehrlic But I didn't use the Q_DECL_EXPORT/Q_DECL_IMPORT in my mainwindow.h...

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I've got the same error and everything I find online states the same issue, with no resolution...